# How could calculate this definite integral by mathematica software

Tags: mathematica

I have a expression given as
$F=f_1(x)+f_2(x)+\cdots+f_N(x)$
Now I want to simplify this integral as
FullSimplify[$\int \limits_0^\infty F \;dx$].
It takes along time to calculate.
If I factor it into small integrals as: $\text{FullSimplify}[\int \limits_0^\infty f_1(x) \; dx] +\cdots+\text{FullSimplify}[\int \limits_0^\infty f_N(x) \; dx$].
It runs faster.
Here, I want to ask that is there any function in the mathematica to factor that kind of integral.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the outer operation in $F$ is addition then

```
FullSimplify[Integrate[#, {x, 0, \[Infinity]}]] & /@ F
```

should do the trick.